# Solve the following differential equation: $\frac {(ydx+xdy)}{(1-x^2y^2)}+xdx=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Is there any way I can get this into the form of a separable, Bernoulli, exact, or any other form of differential equation that is easy to solve?

Solve the following differential equation:

$$\frac{(ydx+xdy)}{(1-x^2y^2)}+xdx=0$$

can someone show me the procedure to simplify or convert this differential equation into a form that is easy to solve?

Comment: Hint:

$$ydx+xdy=d(xy)$$

Comment: @empty Just learn to solve problem yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $xy=u$ and solve $$\int\dfrac{du}{1-u^2}=-\int xdx$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{\mathrm d(xy}{1-(xy)^2}+x\mathrm dx=0 \\ \dfrac{1}{2} \ln \dfrac{1+xy}{1-xy}+\dfrac{x^2}{2} = c, \space some \space constant$